# How to filter resolved tasks that were "In Progress" and assigned to the current user

Tags: jira, jql

I'm looking to make a JIRA filter to get a list of resolved tasks that I have worked on.

Currently I have the following:

```
resolution = Fixed AND assignee was currentUser() AND status was "In Progress" ORDER BY resolutiondate DESC
```

But really I'm looking to only see tasks that were "In Progress" **while** I was assigned to it.

The above picks up too much, any resolved task that went through development that I may have been assigned to during any status.

I'm thinking perhaps I can pull out a date range for the "In Progress" status somehow, but I'd hope there'd be something more simple.

---

*edit* – The user that most often changes the status to "In Progress" is a bot. So `AND status CHANGED TO "In Progress" BY currentUser()` wouldn't work most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we've worked it out for future issues by adding a new field we've called `Resolver`.

We're populating it with the assigned user when an issue is moved to the "In Progress" status.

The JQL I now have is:

```
resolution = Fixed AND (assignee was currentUser() AND status was "In Progress" OR Resolver = currentUser()) ORDER BY resolutiondate DESC`
```

Or if you don't mind missing out on old issues:

```
resolution = Fixed AND Resolver = currentUser() ORDER BY resolutiondate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem and concluded that it is impossible until will be done ["Updated by" search filter](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-1973). Now all filters works separately (assignee, updated, created and etc). Each filter considers only its own conditions. I wrote a script with jira api to use it to check all conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not actually interested in what user changed the status, only what user was *assigned* when the status was updated.

Comment: Unfortunately, with jql it's impossible. At first you can find all tasks which was  "In Progress" and  "assignee was currentUser()". And after that you can use jira api https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JRA-22053?expand=changelog and determine user who changed status on field  "changelog.histories"